# How to use Google Text to Speech (python) in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: pycharm, python-3.8, google-text-to-speech, ubuntu-20.04, gtts

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDH3z.png) is the screenshot of the errors which I am getting. Please help me! I have also installed **mpg321** in my **Ubuntu 20.04**. It is working fine if I play music from terminal. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzzuY.png), I am playing a song from terminal. I've tried to play **hello.mp3** also(from gtts output) from terminal. It's saying hello world when I run from terminal but when I try run in Pycharm it shows errors. Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
#pip install playsound
from playsound import playsound
playsound("fileName.mp3")
```

Hope this resolved your issue.